# What exactly does the #. (sharpsign dot) do in Common Lisp? Is it causing a variable has no value error?

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

Edit: Title updated to reflect what my question should have been, and hopefully lead other users here when they have the same problem.

Little bit of a mess, but this is a work-in-progress common lisp implementation of [anydice](https://anydice.com/) that should output some ascii art representing a probability density function for a hash-table representing dice rolls. I've been trying to figure out exactly why, but I keep getting the error `*** - SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-READER: variable BAR-CHARS has no value` when attempting to run the file in `clisp`. The error is originating from the `output` function.

The code is messy and convoluted (but was previously working if the inner most loop of `output` is replaced with something simpler), but this specific error does not make sense to me. Am I not allowed to access the outer `let*` variables/bindings/whatever from the inner most loop/cond? Even when I substitute `bar-chars` for the list form directly, I get another error that char-decimal has no value either. I'm sure there's something about the loop macro interacting with the cond macro I'm missing, or the difference between `setf`, `let*`, `multiple-value-bind`, etc. But I've been trying to debug this specific problem for hours with no luck.

```lisp
(defun sides-to-sequence (sides)
  (check-type sides integer)
  (loop for n from 1 below (1+ sides) by 1 collect n))

(defun sequence-to-distribution (sequence)
  (check-type sequence list)
  (setf distribution (make-hash-table))
  (loop for x in sequence
    do (setf (gethash x distribution) (1+ (gethash x distribution 0))))
  distribution)

(defun distribution-to-sequence (distribution)
  (check-type distribution hash-table)
  (loop for key being each hash-key of distribution
    using (hash-value value) nconc (loop repeat value collect key)))

(defun combinations (&rest lists)
  (if (endp lists)
      (list nil)
      (mapcan (lambda (inner-val)
                (mapcar (lambda (outer-val)
                          (cons outer-val
                                inner-val))
                        (car lists)))
              (apply #'combinations (cdr lists)))))

(defun mapcar* (func lists) (mapcar (lambda (args) (apply func args)) lists))

(defun dice (left right)
  (setf diceprobhash (make-hash-table))
  (cond ((integerp right)
         (setf right-distribution
               (sequence-to-distribution (sides-to-sequence right))))
        ((listp right)
         (setf right-distribution (sequence-to-distribution right)))
        ((typep right 'hash-table) (setf right-distribution right))
        (t (error (make-condition 'type-error :datum right
                                  :expected-type
                                  (list 'integer 'list 'hash-table)))))
  (cond ((integerp left)
         (sequence-to-distribution
          (mapcar* #'+
                   (apply 'combinations
                     (loop repeat left collect
                       (distribution-to-sequence right-distribution))))))
        (t (error (make-condition 'type-error :datum left
                                  :expected-type
                                  (list 'integer))))))

(defmacro d (arg1 &optional arg2)
  `(dice ,@(if (null arg2) (list 1 arg1) (list arg1 arg2))))

(defun distribution-to-probability (distribution)
  (setf probability-distribution (make-hash-table))
  (setf total-outcome-count
        (loop for value being the hash-values of distribution sum value))
  (loop for key being each hash-key of distribution using (hash-value value)
    do (setf (gethash key probability-distribution)
             (float (/ (gethash key distribution) total-outcome-count))))
  probability-distribution)

(defun output (distribution)
  (check-type distribution hash-table)
  (format t "   #  %~%")
  (let* ((bar-chars (list 9617 9615 9614 9613 9612 9611 9610 9609 9608))
    (bar-width 100)
    (bar-width-eighths (* bar-width 8))
    (probability-distribution (distribution-to-probability distribution)))
    (loop for key being each hash-key of
      probability-distribution using (hash-value value)
      do (format t "~4d ~5,2f ~{~a~}~%" key (* 100 value)
                 (loop for i from 0 below bar-width
                       do (setf (values char-column char-decimal)
                                (truncate (* value bar-width)))
                       collect
                       (cond ((< i char-column)
                              #.(code-char (car (last bar-chars))))
                             ((> i char-column)
                              #.(code-char (first bar-chars)))
                             (t
                              #.(code-char (nth (truncate
                                                 (* 8 (- 1 char-decimal)))
                                                bar-chars)))))))))

(output (d 2 (d 2 6)))
```

This is my first common lisp program I've hacked together, so I don't really want any criticism about formatting/style/performance/design/etc as I know it could all be better. Just curious what little detail I'm missing in the `output` function that is causing errors. And felt it necessary to include the whole file for debugging purposes.

Comment: `#.` is for evaluating forms at read-time. The variable `bar-chars` won't exist until execution-time. You should start by removing them. `char-decimal` should also be defined (with `multiple-value-bind` for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loop`s scoping is perfectly conventional.  But as jkiiski says, [`#.` causes the following form to be evaluated at *read* time](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhf.htm): `bar-chars` is not bound then.

Your code is sufficiently confusing that I can't work out whether there's any purpose to read-time evaluation like this.  But almost certainly there is not: the uses for it are fairly rare.

Comment: Ah yep, that was it. I wasn't sure what the "sharpsign dot" did, but it was used in another answer about accessing unicode characters in lisp portably, which I needed to do. But I applied a transformation to it that I shouldn't have (in an attempt to reduce code duplication), because I didn't know exactly what it did or how to search for it (google doesn't like the query "lisp #."). Also, the error message led me to think it was a scoping thing, or some common pitfall with macros I didn't know about yet.

Thanks!